# GAE/P oauth Invalid token signature が 数%のスマホで発生

Tags: android, python, oauth, google-app-engine

Google App Engine/pythonのサーバーにGoogle Cloud Endpointを使用して
Androidアプリを通信させています。

ユーザーを識別するために OAuth 認証を使用しており、今年6月一杯は正常に動作して
おりました。ところが7月に入ったあたりから1,500台ほどあるAndroidクライアントの内、
1～3%程度で通信が成立しなくなり始め、GAEのログを見るとOAuthのユーザー認証に
失敗しています。

エラーの内容は主に

> id_token verification failed: Invalid token signature

ですが、たまに

> Signature verification error: (失念); continue with the next cert.

のようなエラーも混じります。

問題が発生する一月程度前からサーバーもアプリも変更を加えておらず、発生するスマホ
のメーカーやAndroidバージョンに法則性はなさそうです。
一度発生したスマホでは常に発生し、アプリを再インストールしても改善しません。

あと、直接関係ないかもしれませんが、コンソールの
App Engine > Quotas > VIEW USAGE HISTORY
が 6/29, 6/30 と普段の倍の金額になったあと 7/1 が2回記録され、以後本日まで
日付が表示されておりません。
(OAuth認証に成功した場合の処理は全て正常に行われており、料金は発生するはずです)
過去約半年運用してきましたが非常に安定してこのようなことはありませんでした。

Endpoints や pycrypto のバージョン変更等を行いましたが改善しませんでした。

質問としては
1, OAuth関連の問題の解決策はありますか？ 
又は同じような問題が起こった方はいらっしゃいますか？

2, Quotas/使用料金 に関して同じような問題が起こった方はいらっしゃいますか？

3, Googleの助けを得たい場合どのような方法がありますか？
できれば費用がかからないほうが望ましいです。

解決の糸口がつかめずたいへん困っています。
何らかの情報をお持ちの方、どうかお教え願います。

Answer (score 2):

ソースが無いので、憶測ではありますが、ぱっと思いつくのは

- ユーザがアプリの認可を取り消した
- tokenの有効期限が切れた

とかでしょうか。

Quotaはあまり見てなかったですが、僕も7/1より後は表示されてないですね。

[image: quota]

Googleのサポートを受ける方法ですが、 https://cloud.google.com/support/ にあります。
無料だと、 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine で質問するという手順になります。